# How to install glib2.14 in centos along with existing glib in centos 6.7

Tags: centos, glibc

I wont able to run my electron app in centos 6.7 which says,

**G_LIB2.14** and **G_LIB2.15** not found...  i gone through many sites since which says updating glib was not a good method will affect other UI in OS level since Linux is self destructive...

i tested with **Virtual Machine** updating `glibc into 2.14` which causes **Trash folder** unusable.. how do i get rid out of it?

is there a way to install glib specific version in centos 6.7 specific to specific app along with keep existing glib as it is? in my case it is electron app.

looking for better solution?

Comment: `G_LIB2.14 and G_LIB2.15` : Unknown objects. Besides that, glib 2.14 is not glibc 2.14. .... `glib2` is the "GIMP tool kit". `glibc` is the system C library. ... Which "electron app" is it about ? ? Please edit your question : electron app - name.